# Appium push for iOS real device (on AWS) not working

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-ios, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to push some images to my iOS device (that is on AWS device farm)

The push method works for iOS simulator, but when run on the AWS, I get a timeout exception.

The size of the image is relatively small (just a random image as a test)

This is the error I get on the push from AWS Device farm:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not push the file within the given timeout 60000ms. Original error: operation timed out
```

---

The code for pushing an image looks like this:

```
    String fileName = "testFile.jpeg";
    File imageToPush = getImgFromUrl(fileName);
    try{
        driver.pushFile(fileName,imageToPush);

        System.out.println("\n\n---IMAGE Push Successful---");
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("\n\nFailed to upload image to device\n\n");
        System.out.println("\n\nReason:\n\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

This snippet work for iOS Simulator.

Returns timeout exception for iOS Device on AWS device farm.
How could I make it work?

Comment: There are some compatibility concerns on the [`driver.pushFile(..)`](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/files/push-file/) command. Can you verify that the device and Appium version you are running on is compatible? Also, can you validate the file actually exists where you are expecting it too on the remote host?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment,
The file exists, that is for sure, for the sake of testing it I download an image from web, which was working on simulator too, so the problem is really with the pushFile(..)
on AWS:
Appium version: APPIUM_VERSION=1.19.0. The device used is Apple iPhone 12

Comment: What do your appium logs show? Can you update the question with a pastebin of them? Also, which versions of AWS Device Farm's WDA are you using?

Comment: Hey,
I'm not sure where i would find the WDA version.
The (useable) appium log is right in the question, there's no related info before that

Comment: It is defined in the `.yml` file that you are using

Comment: I'm not that familiar with this script, If I understand it correctly (it uses a lot of if-s but I guess this is a default template)
In case of appium 1.19 it goes to $DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V6 which is v2.20.8 for WebDriverAgent

Comment: What do your Appium logs show?

Comment: In the logs we have, it only shows logs from the device farm, and testng / cucumber. Unless there's an error, there we get a stacktrace, and for that I provided the only relevant line ( the timeout exception)

is there a way to add appium server logs also to this? if yes then i will try to do that tomorrow and provide logs

Comment: AWS Device Farm provides logs for anything placed in the `$DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR` folder. If using one of the sample testspec files for appium, then this includes the `appium.txt` file for Appium logs. It will show up in a `.zip` file on the console under Files > Tests Suite > Customer Artifacts for the selected job.